# PHP use statement failing

Tags: php, namespaces

I wanted to try out the [FlawkApi](https://github.com/nybouchard/FlawkApi) library and copied the sample page for Steam accounts.

PHP is generating an error however:

> Fatal error: Class 'FlawkApi\Services\Steam' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SteamAccount\index.php on line 18

The code in question is this:

```
use FlawkApi\Services\Steam;

// include bootstrap
require_once (__DIR__.'/bootstrap.php');

// initiate Steam with example gamerid and httpClient
$FlawkApi = new Steam($gamerIds['steam']['id'], $httpClientProvider());
```

That last line is line 18.

Bootstrap.php holds this:

```
// error reporting on
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// include some example gamer ids
require_once (__DIR__.'/init.php');
```

And init.php holds this(modified ID here, real ID is in the actual code):

```
$gamerIds = array(
    'steam' =>
    array(
        'id' => 'myId'
    )
);

$httpClientProvider = function() {
            return new \FlawkApi\Common\Http\Client\FlawkClient();
        };
```

This is a simple use statement that PHP is falling over. My PHP version is 5.4.7, installed from the latest XAMPP version.

Does anyone know what this wouldn't work?

EDIT: initialized the composer.json, it created the vendor folder. I then required vendor/autoload.php, but it still generates the same error.

EDIT2: Here's a screenshot of the folder structure and the composer.json file:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use spl_autoload_register to register function which can load the class if class is not found.

e.g

```
function my_autoloader($class) {
   if(file_exists(__DIR__ . $class . ".php"))
        require_once(__DIR__ . $class . ".php");
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
```

Comment: Flawk uses composer. So just include `vendor/autoload.php`.

Comment: According to the documentation, it should: [http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Comment: @Evert: So, I have to add a composer.json file first in the root?

Comment: @KoenDG depends on if you installed the library as a composer dependency, or if you just did a `git clone`. If it's the latter, you can simply install composer and run `composer install` in the same directory as `composer.json`.

Comment: @Evert I got it initially as a `git clone`. I copied the FlawkApi folder to my documentroot and also the composer.json file, which I also ran an install on. I'll check tomorrow what happens if I only import the composer.json file and run an install on it.